# Updating the array by comparing it with newly inserting elements

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to get the update the elements in an array by comparing it with the upcoming elements.

An example for this is like let us take four arrays

```
a1[]={14,14,25,25,38,128}//combination like 1 and 4  
a2[]={33,55,44,55,22,332}//cost for the combination is 3 and 3
```

these two are the existing arrays
now the another two arrays

```
a3[]={146,146}  
a4[]={333,666}
```

now the result should be like the final arrays as

```
a1[]={146,14,25,25,38,128,146}  
a2[]={333,55,44,55,22,332,666}
```

Comment: do you want to add one element at first and another as last element of array?

Comment: Did you use the proper tags? The codes look like javascript, not php.

Comment: it looks like you want to bookend the array with the numbers in a3 and a4, is that your 'comparison'?

Comment: i want to update the element in a1 while comparing the cost of the element i.e in a2 like the first element in a1 is 14 and its cost is 33 in a2 array now the element in a3 is 146 and its cost is 333, now the comparison is 14 and 146 the two bits are common and the cost for these combinations is also common like 33 and 333 so i want to update 14 and 33 as 146 and 333

Answer (score 0):

Hope you want to remove the first element and need to add the first and last from the another array. For easiness i used single array here as input

```
$dataArr = array(array(14,14,25,25,38,128),array(33,55,44,55,22,332));
$replaceArr = array(array(146,146),array(333,666));
$finalArr = array();
foreach ($dataArr AS $key => $data) {
    array_shift($data);
    $first = reset($replaceArr[$key]);
    $end = end($replaceArr[$key]);
    $finalArr[$key] = array_merge(array($first), $data, array($end));
}
echo "<pre>";print_r($finalArr);echo "</pre>";
```

Comment: thanks it is updating the first element but when i am changing the arrays as  a1[]={14,14,25,25,38,128}  a2[]={33,55,44,55,22,332}  and a3[]={146,256}  a4[]={333,555} the result should be a1[]={146,14,25,256,38,128} and a2[]={333,55,44,555,22,332}

Comment: Your requirement is not clear.In your question input contain 6 elements and out put 7. And in your comment it is different. Please explain clearly your requirement

Comment: you see the first element in a1 and a3 they are 14 and 146  and their cost in a2 and a4 they are 33 and 333 now the first two digits of a1 and a3 are matching and at the same time a2 and a4 are also matching  i.e 14-33/146-333 the 14 is updated as 146 and 33 as 333 and the comment i have mentioned before contains elements 146 and 256 in a3 and their cost as 333 and 555 now in a1 and a2 there is combination of 14-33 and 25-55 are matching with a3 and a4 these has to be updated in a1 and a2 and the new elements are to be added(matching elements should be updated and new elements should be added)